# Send custom utm_source with gtag?

Tags: google-analytics

I have this code and I'd like to send a utm_source/content... that is custom.

```
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', window.GA_TRACKING_ID, {
    send_page_view: false,
  });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031948/passing-utm-tags-to-google-analytics-with-google-tag-manager-in-javascript-not-w

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Moved the pageview trigger after setting the values.

This should work

```
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('set', {'campaignName': 'Facebook'});
gtag('set', {'campaignSource': 'Social'});
gtag('set', {'campaignMedium': 'Social Instant Article'});
gtag('config', window.GA_TRACKING_ID);
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work... It only records direct traffic.

Comment: Can you try again. Moved the pageview after setting the values