# Passing UTM Tags to Google Analytics with Google Tag Manager in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, analytics.js

I'm trying to send utms (medium, source) to Google Analytics directly in Javascript code (not via the URL), for every visit to my page. This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-52626777-6"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('set', {
        'campaignName':'MyCampaignName',
        'campaignMedium':'MyMedium',
        'campaignSource':'MySource'
    });

    gtag('config', 'UA-11111111-1');

</script>
```

For some reason, even though Google Analytics is tracking pageviews in real-time correctly, it doesn't seem to be getting the Medium and Source. Both show *(none)* and *(direct)* respectively:
[image]

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: I made changes to the above JS code to reflect XTOTHEL's feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config tag should fire AFTER the sets.

Also gtag('set', {campaign: {medium: 'myMedium', source: 'mySource'}});

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't work. I now have gtag('set', {'campaignMedium':'MyMedium'}); gtag('set', {'campaignSource':'MySource'}); gtag('config', 'UA-52626777-6'); but it's still not tracking them in GA.

Comment: Updated another way, can you try that?

Comment: This works! nice one. Google's documentation on this is horrific.